# Can I get the same information in the Facebook "Like" button via the JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I've been reading through the [Facebook developer documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/) for a couple of hours now, but have yet to determine whether what I'm trying to do is possible.

I'd like to display the same information that's shown in the ["Like" button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) in a custom way; that is, rather than just including the "Like" button on a page with the HTML5, XFBML or iframe methods, I want to get access to the underlying data via JavaScript to then display it in my own way:

- Number of likes for a given URL (if any).
- Names of the logged-in user's friends who like the given URL (if any).

One constraint is that, due to how I'll be implementing this (it will be a third-party script included on other websites), I can't prompt the user for permission/[authorization](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

My questions are:

- Is this possible?
- If so, how exactly do I access this data? I think I've found a way to get the number of likes for a given URL (using [an FQL query like this](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20like_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%22http://www.stackoverflow.com%22)), but would appreciate suggestions if there's an alternative (and preferable) way.
- Will the constraint that I mentioned prevent me from accessing friends' names that like a URL? If so, how does the "Like" button work without requiring authorization? Is it because the iframe is served from www.facebook.com, which is already authorized?

Thanks for any help! Code examples are also very much appreciated.

Comment: you already found your answer for likes. as for the friends, you dont know the current user's FB ID without authorize them, so you cant fetch friends of the user.

Comment: @Rufinus: Thanks - I'm not sure if it's an important distinction, but I don't necessarily need to query directly for friends of the logged-in user, but rather just determine if anyone who likes a given URL happens to be friends of the logged-in user. I've only begun to peek at FQL, so that might just be two ways of describing the same thing. Any guesses why the "Like" button doesn't have this limitation? Is it not built on the same API, or does the fact that it's served in a facebook.com (i.e., first-party) iframe explain it?

Answer (score 0):

your constraint is unfortunate, as you'll need an access_token for FQL queries.  If the user is logged in on the parent frame then you may be able to pull the access_token from there, but otherwise it's not going to work.

If you got it working somehow, please correct me and let us know how you got it to work.

Answer (score -1):

I know that you can catch "Like" and "Unlike" event when user clicks it.

So that you can catch that event through

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', addfunction );
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', removefunction );
```

In those add function and remove function,

You can record current reading article or page and increase or decrease number of likes.

In that way, you can trace number of likes per page by querying from your database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but I'm not sure it helps me in this case. I need to gather information from arbitrary third-party URLs where I won't be able to run any JavaScript. Also, I think that this would accomplish the same thing as a call to the API (like https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20like_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%22http://www.stackoverflow.com%22). Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding, though.